# Integration of WYSIWYG editor to best-in-place textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, best-in-place

I'm using best_in_place gem to editing client's info in-place.

My question is, how can I integrate a WYSIWYG Editor for editing this content as HTML?
I'm currently using this editor: https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails/

I'm not good at javascript and cofeescript, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

**My code in view:**

```
<%= best_in_place @client, :info, :type => :textarea, :nil => "Click here to add content!", :html_attrs => { class: "wysihtml5" }, :sanitize => false %>
```

**And clients.js.cofee**

```
$(document).ready ->

# Activating Best In Place
jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place()

# Loading editor
$(".wysihtml5").each (i, elem) ->
$(elem).wysihtml5()
```

Does anyone knows what to do about it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you eventually solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, **inner_class: "wysihtml5"** if present activate WisiHTML5 editor, buttons 'Save' and 'Cancel' must be present (default event handler disabled for correct work)

**In show.html.erb:**

```
  <%= best_in_place @client, :info, type: :textarea, 
                                    nil: "Click here to add content!", 
                                    inner_class: "wysihtml5", 
                                    sanitize: false,
                                    ok_button: 'Save',
                                    cancel_button: 'Cancel',
                                    display_with: lambda { |v| v.html_safe }
  %>
```

**In coffee script file:**

```
jQuery ->
  # WisiHTML5 Edit
  $('.best_in_place')
    # append
    .best_in_place()
    # init
    .on 'best_in_place:activate', () -> 
      if $(this).attr('data-inner-class') == 'wysihtml5'
        html = $(this).attr('data-original-content')
        area = $('textarea', this)
        area.addClass('span7').unbind('blur')
        area.wysihtml5().data('wysihtml5').editor.on 'load', (e)->
          this.setValue(html, true)
    # update
    .on 'best_in_place:success', (e, data) ->
      if $(this).attr('data-inner-class') == 'wysihtml5'
        attr = $(this).attr('data-attribute')
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
        if data[attr]
          $(this).attr('data-original-content', data[attr])
          $(this).html(data[attr])
```

**In show.json.jbuilder:**

```
json.extract! @client, :info, ... <any other attributes>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a simple indentation issue of coffeescript. Just indent the lines below $(document).ready ->  by a tab.

```
$(document).ready ->
  # Activating Best In Place
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place()

  # Loading editor
  $(".wysihtml5").each (i, elem) ->
  $(elem).wysihtml5()
```

To validate further, copy your code in the coffeescript frame @ http://js2coffee.org/: the resulting javascript should look like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
  $(".wysihtml5").each(function(i, elem) {});
  return $(elem).wysihtml5();
});
```

That is, the plugins should be called after the dom is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over every element with class "wysihtml5" so it should be this way.

```
$(function(){
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
  $.each('.wysihtml5', function(i, elem){
    $(elem).wysihtml5();
  });
});
```

And converted to Coffee with [Js2Coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) it should work.

```
$ ->
 jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place()
 $.each ".wysihtml5", (i, elem) ->
   $(elem).wysihtml5()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CK-Editor, which I believe would similar to your wysiwyg Editor case somehow.

Here is an example and solution for that:
Long article about how he is switching to this:

http://blog.amps211.com/this-is-me-professing-my-love-for-jquery-and-how-i-got-ckeditor-working-with-jeditable/

files to the editor update
http://blog.amps211.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/jquery.generateId.js
http://blog.amps211.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/jquery.jeditable.ckeditor.js

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with this myself, and it was not obvious to say the least.

This is how I eventually got it working:

You need to call `wysihtml5()` on the textarea element, bound to `best_in_place:activate` event. This is my `application.js.coffee`:

```
$(".best_in_place").each (index, element) ->
  $element  = $(element)

  $element
  .best_in_place()
  .on 'best_in_place:activate', () ->
    $element.find(".wysihtml5").each ->
      $this = $(this)
      $this.wysihtml5()
```

I added the `wysihtml5` css class using `inner_class` option on the helper:

```
<%= best_in_place @client, :info, type: :textarea, nil: "Click here to add content!", inner_class: 'wysihtml5' }, sanitize: false, display_as: :info_html %>
```

Note that I'm using `display_as: :info_html`, since I have that field on the model to store processed html, but you can use `display_with: lambda { |v| v.html_safe }` if that is not your case.

And now it comes the tricky part: the current version (3.0.3) of `best_in_place` does not play nice with `wysihtml5` since the textarea got blurred to be substituted by the `contenteditable iframe`, what in turn made the editable operation to be cancelled. I needed to roll a few modifications to the gem on my own that I hope that got merged (you can see the [full discussion here](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/issues/452)), but in the meanwhile you can use [my fork](https://github.com/dgilperez/best_in_place). If you do that, then you need to provide your view helper this extra option: `skip_blur: true`.